# Android Firebase - version number of Firebase UI & Android design support libraries for Android SDK 24

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making a Chat Android app, and require the version number of Firebase UI & Android design support libraries for Android SDK 24.

I have got the below given version numbers from a link, but they are not compatible with sdk 24 but are only compatible with sdk 23.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
```

I have searched Firebase website, but couldn't locate the new version no of these libraries.

Where can I find the updated version number for these library files?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android ? last version of firebase UI is "1.0.1", as for the design support version you can use IntelliJ detector or head over to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html.

Comment: Nope none of the 2 websites have it, although i got the support design library: compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

Comment: But i haven't yet found the version number of Firebase UI library

Comment: This table regroups all of the versions for Firebase UI https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Comment: FirebaseUI Version- 1.0.1 for Firebase/Play Services Version- 10.0.0.        But i require Firebase UI for Firebase/Play Services Version- 10.0.1.

Comment: I don't think they have released a version for 10.0.1. You may have to wait until they release it or change play service version to 10.0.0 .. Btw are you getting any error while using 10.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

[Android Support Library revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

[FirebaseUI versions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

As of now 25.3.1 is the stable version for the support library and 2.0.1 for FirebaseUI.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is  `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'`

Check Out - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app

How it work -https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/08/build-better-mobile-apps-with-firebaseui_78.html

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with version 0.4.0 of firebase-ui-database:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
}
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```